# how to take summation

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have a table in a database as below:

```
id   place_id        minutes    spent_time
___   _________     ______   ___________
1       1              0        2
1       1              5        3
1       1              10       2
1       2              10       3
1       2              15       3
1       2              20       9
```

Here minute is 0 means interval(0-5 minutes).So in 10-15 minutes it was in place_id 1 for 2 minutes and rest in place_id 2.

This gives the time spent in each five_minutes.So I want to know the total time spent in place_id 1 before moving to place 2.Which means 2+3+2=7 minutes in the place 1 before going to place 2.

I tried rle(df$place_id) which will give

```
3   3
1   2
```

But how to sum up the spent time for these blocks?

Comment: I get a different number by summing `2+3 + 2 #[1] 7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `aggregate`:

```
> a
  id place_id minutes spent_time
1  1        1       0          2
2  1        1       5          3
3  1        1      10          2
4  1        2      10          3
5  1        2      15          3
6  1        2      20          9
> aggregate(a$spent_time, by=list(Category=a$place_id), FUN=sum)
      place_id spent_time
  1      1       7
  2      2       15
```

You can also use `tapply` as shown below:

```
> tapply(a$spent_time, a$place_id, FUN=sum)
   place_id    spent_time
    1              7 
    2              15
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use group by operation

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(id, place_id) %>%
    summarise(spent_time = sum(spent_time))
```

---

Or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(spent_time ~ id + place_id, df1, FUN = sum)
```